# matplotlib set color of legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am generating a plot using matplot lib to plot many points (~a few thousand) by doing the following:

```
labels = []
for item in items:
        label = item[0]
        labels.append(label)
        plt.plot(item[1][0], item[1][1], 'ro', c = colors[item], label = str(label))
```

And then generating a legend by doing:

`plt.legend([str(x) for x in np.unique(labels)])`

However, for each label in the legend the corresponding color is the same (not the color in the plot). Is there any way to manually set the color for the legend.

I have attached a sample plot to illustrate the problem.
[image]

--EDIT--
Just calling `plt.legend()` as suggested by some does not seem to solve the problem for me, it adds a legend entry for each point. See the image below for an example output:
[image]

Comment: Just use `plt.legend()`. It will find the labels that you have set in the calls to `plot`.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
labels = []
for item in items:
    label = item[0]
    plt.plot(item[1][0], item[1][1], 'o', c=colors[item], label=str(label))
plt.legend()
```

If you specify the labels directly when creating the artist (in the call to `plot`), you can just call `plt.legend()` without arguments. It will iterate through the artists in the current axis and use their labels. That way the colors in the legend will match the ones in the plot.

Comment: I have edited the questions showing the response I get when doing this. Basically it adds a legend entry for each point

Comment: Oh, you shouldn't plot each point separately! this is very inefficient. For each cluster, collect all points and plot them in a single call to `plt.plot`

Comment: how do I do that? Could you provide an example. Right now `items` is just a list of tuples `(label, [x,y])`

Comment: please edit your answer with the comment about plotting all points in each cluster together and I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create fake line markers and use them as legend entries:

```
markers = [plt.Line2D([0,0],[0,0], color=color[item], marker='o', linestyle='') for item in np.unique(items)]
plt.legend(markers, np.unique(labels), numpoints=1)
```

You can see a complete example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31311862/4077912).

Note that I have not tested this and you might need to adjust `np.unique(items)` to your actual data set. `color` is assumed to be a dictionary with colors for your items.